# mask and apply numpy where function to a vector in c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, where-clause, mask

I'm using C++ and want to combine the masking of a vector and the search for the indexes where a condition is verified, similarly to the numpy *where* function.

Here's an example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> id     = {61, 66, 68, 80}
std::vector<int> val    = {0, 0, 2, 1};
std::vector<int> offset = {62, 65, 70};
std::vector<int> masked;
```

After using

```cpp
masked = offset[val];
```

`masked` should look like this: `masked = {62, 62, 70, 65}`

Afterwards, I want to find the indexes where `id` vector elements are greater than `masked` ones. Both vectors have the same length. This is equivalent to Numpy's *where* function in Python.

```py
c = np.where(id > masked)[0]
```

`c` is an equivalent of `vector<int>` and should look like this: `c = {1,3}`

Any ideas out there? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple loop. Note that you do not need the intermediate array `masked`. Here is an (untested) example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> c;
c.reserve(val.size());

for(size_t i=0 ; i<val.size() ; ++i)
    if(id[i] > Offset[val[i]])
        c.push_back(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Numpy-like manipulation of arrays, you can use `std::valarray`:

```
std::valarray<std::size_t> val = {0, 0, 2, 1};
std::valarray<int> id     = {61, 66, 68, 80}
std::valarray<int> offset = {62, 65, 70};
std::valarray<int> masked = offset[val];
```

Note that the `value_type` of `val` must be `std::size_t`, as `std::valarray<int>` is not implicitly convertible to `std::valarray<std::size_t>` (differently from what happens with `int` and `std::size_t`).

For the second part, if you can use C++11, then you may use `std::iota` (defined in `<numeric>`) which creates an incrementing sequence:

```
std::valarray<int> where(id.size());
std::iota(begin(where), end(where), 0);
```

Then you can do:

```
std::valarray<int> c = where[id > masked];
```

You may prefer this writing for readability, although it might be less performant. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/yY7h5JYp3) you should find the code example.